# Switching to a child theme

Tags: themes, child-theme, parent-theme

I am using the Zephyr theme for my site, but want to switch to a child theme as this seems to be recommended in case the theme is updated. I am worried I will lose my customization etc.

Are there any safeguards against this?

Comment: Child theme will not change any of your customization. You can safely create your own and make template modifications

Answer (score 0):

Child themes are simply themes themselves, which inherit functionalities from their parent theme.

This means, Just like any other theme, if they are not updated manually, they will not change. However, you should check the change log for the parent theme, each time you update it, and then update your child theme accordingly, if necessary.

This is due to core changes, since some functions might be removed or changed in the parent theme, which you might be using in your child theme.

Answer (score 0):

You won't lose your changes to the parent theme unless you update it, and the updated theme overwrites your customized files. Switching to a child theme will allow you to copy those modified parent files to the child theme folder. This will preserve them in the event of an update to the parent theme.

Use a file comparison tool such as WinMerge http://winmerge.org/about/ to compare your current parent theme folder to the stock/unmodified theme folder. This will identify modified parent theme files. Next, copy those modified files to the new child theme folder. This will preserve your changes in the event of a parent theme update.

[image]